# Regex capture all matches in word

Tags: regex, match

For example, I have this string:

```
222
```

What pattern I should use to get a count of "22" matches exactly 2 times?

```
222 -> (22)2 and 2(22)
```

So, for 2222 I would have 3 matches:

```
2222 -> (22)22 and 2(22)2 and 22(22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Positive Lookahead:

```
2(?=2)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/gGLv4k/1

Answer (score -1):

Try `2{2}`. The number inside the braces is the number of repetitions of the token prior to the opening brace.